# Is the "storage server" included in any wso2 stratos vmware image?

Tags: wso2, wso2-stratos

Is the "storage server" included in any wso2 stratos vmware image ?
In which version ?

I ask it because I see that it's available on stratos live.

I would like to install it on premise using a vmware image

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Storage server 1.0.3 is now available as a separate product. You can downloaded it from [here](http://wso2.com/products/storage-server/).

Answer (score 0):

Storage Server is available with the [Stratos 1.6 local setup](http://wso2.com/cloud/stratos/). It is a new addition to StratosLive. It is not yet available as a separate product to download.